# Select values is a row as column values

Tags: sql, oracle-sqldeveloper

How can I retrieve values in a row as column values?

Example:

Consider the output of below query as **INPUT** :

```
Select 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10 
from dual;
```

I need a query that can give below output:

```
COL1
----
 1
 2
 3
 4
 5
 6
 7
 8
 9
10
```

Comment: Why not "select 1 from dual union all select 2 from dual etc."?

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT 1 AS "COL1" FROM dual
UNION
SELECT 2 FROM dual
UNION
SELECT 3 FROM dual
UNION
SELECT 4 FROM dual
UNION
SELECT 5 FROM dual
UNION
SELECT 6 FROM dual
UNION
SELECT 7 FROM dual
UNION
SELECT 8 FROM dual
UNION
SELECT 9 FROM dual
UNION
SELECT 10 FROM dual ;
```

Comment: Is there any other way than this, the method suggested has multiple UNIONs and SELECTs. Is there some other method.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to generate a sequence of numbers in Oracle:

```
with n as (
      select level as n
      from dual
      connect by level <= 10 
     )
select *
from n;
```

Or, if you have 10 columns, you can do an unpivot.  An easy way is with `union all`:

```
select col1 from t union all
select col2 from t union al
. . .
select col10 from t;
```